# Parceljs on Alpine build throws: Cannot find module './artifacts/index.linux-arm64-musl.node'

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux, parceljs, apple-silicon

I'm trying to build a website with Parceljs using Docker with a node:current-alpine (16.5.0-alpine3.13) container on an Apple Silicon Mac.

Every time I try to build the website i get the error below. I'm out of ideas, as I've also tried several versions of node:alpine images and all of them fail with the same error, and I don't know how to make it work.

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
 Build failed.
Error: Cannot find module './artifacts/index.linux-arm64-musl.node'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/source-map/parcel_sourcemap_node/index.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/source-map/dist/node.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/worker.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/child.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/threads/ThreadsChild.js
Error: Cannot find module './artifacts/index.linux-arm64-musl.node'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/source-map/parcel_sourcemap_node/index.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/source-map/dist/node.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/worker.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/child.js
- /app/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/threads/ThreadsChild.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@parcel/source-map/parcel_sourcemap_node/index.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
```